# V is a n-dimensional vector space and $T : V \rightarrow V$ is a LT s.t $rank(T) = rank(T^2)$. Prove that $range(T)\cap ker(T) = \{\mathbb{0}\}$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations

> V is a n-dimensional vector space and $T : V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation s.t $rank(T) = rank(T^2)$. Prove that $range(T)\cap ker(T) = \{\mathbb{0}\}$

I am stuck with this problem and don't know how to proceed. My working so far:

$T^2 = T \circ T: V \rightarrow V$

By the rank theorem:

$rank(T) + nullity(T) = dim(V)$

$rank(T^2) + nullity(T^2) = dim(V)$

$\Longrightarrow rank(T) + nullity(T) = rank(T^2) + nullity(T^2)$

$\Longrightarrow nullity(T) = nullity(T^2)$ (By hypothesis)

Where can I go from here?

Comment: here is a hint, the assumption implies that T in bijective on its range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with what you have. We know that $\ker(T)\subseteq\ker(T^2)$, so by the nullity result we must have $\ker(T)=\ker(T^2)$. Now if $y=Tx\in\ker(T)$, then $T^2x=Ty=0$, so $x\in\ker(T^2)=\ker(T)$, so $y=Tx=0$.

Comment: Why do we know that $ker(T) \subseteq ker(T^2)$?

Comment: @Joeyboy If $Tx=0$, then $T^2x=T(Tx)=T0=0$.